# parsing custom log in Logstash

Tags: parsing, logstash, grok

I want to ask your help in parsing my logs in custom format. I tried to use http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ for discover my log format, but unfortunately I didn't succeed. my log has the next format:

```
#AdressHost#TypeLogs|OrganizationName|user@mail.com|CallMethod|ExecutionTimeOnDB|ExecutionTimeOnAppServer|Date Time
```

for example:

```
#mac.frozm.com#CallInfo|Jonsens|jack.lellow@jonsens.com|GetTotalsInfo|19|3|2014-05-11 07:49:10
```

I try to use the following pattern:

```
#%{URIHOST}#CallInfo|Jonsens|%{USER:auth}@%{URIPROTO}|GetTotalsInfo|%{NUMBER:duration}|0|%{DATESTAMP} %{TIME}
```

but Logstash keeps throwing "_grokparsefailure"
Can you help me or might suggest another way for parsing log in the Logstash tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
GetTotalsInfo|19|3|
```

does not seem to match up with this part of your pattern:

```
GetTotalsInfo|%{NUMBER:duration}|0|
```

as you specify a 0 in the pattern where in your example you have a 3.

Here's a general piece of advice when building grok patterns. Do small pieces of the pattern at a time, and check to see if they work first before building up a larger pattern. You can use this to debug patterns that are giving you trouble, taking each individual piece and testing them.

For example, just start out with a pattern like this and check to see if it works:

```
"^#%{URIHOST}"
```

(the ^ is a regex anchor that guarantees there are no preceding characters)
Build up from there.

I hope this helped!